# Estimating the proportion of observations inside a given interval

Tags: confidence-interval, proportion

I have a question which should be a failry common question, but for which I can not find any reference.
For simplicity, we will assume that our variables are all i.i.d and normally distributed.
I take a sample of some incoming parts, and measure a dimension. I obtain a mean m, and a standard deviation s. I also have an engineering specification which says that this dimension should be between LL and UL (lower and upper limits). I am trying to figure out, based on what I measured on the sample, the interval (min and max) proportion of parts I could expect to be "in spec". I.e. some interval which says that at least min% of the parts  can be expected in spec, and at most max% of the parts can be expected to be in spec. I could use the standard normal distribution, but this assumes that I know the sample mean and standard deviation, which I do not (only have an estimate). So what I compute with the Z distribution will underestimate [min, max], as it does not account for the expected variability in the measured m and s statistics.
I am not trying to get a tolerance interval (based on the normal distribution): that would tell be that P% will be within a given interval at a certain confidence level. I am trying to get basically the reverse: given an interval [LL, UL], what percentage of observations could lie in this interval, at a given confidence level.
It would seem to be a typical problem for any manufacturing operation, but I am drawing blanks?
Thaks

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a variation of the *prediction interval*. Consider your sample of incoming parts as independent realisations $(x_1, \cdots, x_n)$ generated from some process $X\sim N(\mu, \sigma)$ (let's assume it's normally distributed).

From them, you calculate the sample mean $\hat\mu$ and the sample standard deviation $\hat \sigma$ according to the standard formulae. We now have an estimate of $X$. This is $\hat X \sim N(\hat\mu, \hat\sigma)$.

We are then interested in knowing the proportion of parts which lie within the interval $(\text{LL}, \text{UL})$. This is the simple calculation $Pr(\text{LL} < \hat X < \text{UL})$, which you can calculate easily from most statistical packages.

This is probably good enough to get by with. We have ignored the fact that $\hat\mu$ and $\hat\sigma$ each have uncertainty associated with them. If this worries you, you could do a bootstrap to account for this. But if your sample size $n$ is large enough it's probably not worth worrying about.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As you indicated, this is the "basic" answer; just look it up in a Z table, and I would have my answer. But then all I get a a point estimate of that proportion (just like I got a point estimate of the mean and sd).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As you indicated, this is the "basic" answer; just look it up in a Z table, and I would have my answer. But then all I get a a point estimate  ̂p of that proportion (just like I got a point estimate of the mean and sd).
What I am really after is the "confidence interval" of the proportion, e.g. there is 95% confidence that we will find between p1 and p2 inside (LL, UL). And indeed p1 and p2 will take into account the uncertainties on μ^ and σ^. I have not found any source on this...

Comment: Tbh I'd probably just try a bootstrap method.